# Can't set custom class name

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, xcode4.2

I can't seem to be able to set the identity of my view to `GraphViewController` in Xcode 4.2.

I dragged a regular `UIView` in storyboard on a `UIScrollView`.

I create a new file called `GraphViewController` extending `UIViewController` (`.h` and `.m`) but when I click on my view in storyboard and try to set the custom class name (its identity) to `GraphViewController`, it doesn't set it. It doesn't even show it in the dropdown list.

Am I missing something here a connection or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set any class inherited from `UIView` to a `UIView` instance.
But you have created a `UIViewController` subclass, not a `UIView` subclass.

You can assign your custom class to the controller, not to the view.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever makes the dumb mistake I just did... ensure you have created an appropriate storyboard for either iOS or OS X. Adding the wrong one to your project will certainly cause issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was making sure I was clicking on the controller's top tool bar, and not the "screen" UI frame. If you select the frame or anything in it, your Identity Inspector will be looking at the View, or other elements in the storyboard, instead of the controller itself.